# Embedded Google Calendar Not Showing Events

Tags: html, google-calendar-api

I have created a simple website written in HTML. For my website, I wanted to embed the Google Calendar and the weather forecast. I have successfully accomplished that, and I can view the Google Calendar and the weather forecast. Furthermore, I am using my Mac as a web server. I can view the the webpage by typing in the URL: localhost/Pi.html. However, the only problem is I cannot view any events on my Google Calendar. When I load my webpage all I see is a blank calendar and my weather forecast. I have tried multiple times making my calendar public and making sure the sharing settings are correct but, I keep having the same issues.

Here's the embed code I'm using at the moment:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=GMAILNAME%40gmail.com&amp;color=%2329527A&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> id="kallender"></iframe>
```

Comment: My Mac is hosting the HTML file, and I can use my IP address on other PCs to view the web page.

Comment: Please provide some of the code you have tried in attempting this.

Comment: Could you post that as a code block in the original answer? It's a bit hard to read in the comments section

Comment: If you have a google account you can go to your calendar settings. There is a sharing setting that allows you to embed your google calendar with HTML code. That's where I got that piece of code from

Comment: I gave that a go and the embed code worked, if you paste the embed code into the HTML section of http://jsfiddle.net and hit the 'run' button- do you get an empty calendar?

Comment: As an update, mine seems to show the events without any additional work:
https://i.imgur.com/epgkoVl.png?1 (don't ask why I only sleep on thursdays)

Comment: I just tried it and it generated the calendar with limits. I AM NO LONGER GETTING A EMPTY CALENDAR!!! I went back into my files and updated the HTML code I may have copied something wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was because I used a piece of code that was provided to me. Like a blsajfdlkf;as dfjk *Insert your calendar code here* jdaskfl;saf.

Comment: It's always the jdaskfl;saf's that get ya ;) Glad I was able to help.